# Invalid assignment operator in Java

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I'm running a super basic program for my class on Java with eclipse, the point of it to write a for loop that prints odd number from 1 to 99 (inclusive) and I'm writing my code

```
int num1 = 1;
int num2 = 99;
for (num1 => num2 ;; num1 + 2)
    System.out.println(num1);
```

and it's telling me that `+` and `>=` are invalid AssignmentOperators. Why is it doing this?

Comment: `System.out.println()` is Java, not Javascript; so, are you trying to write Java or Javascript?

Comment: This is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems there. The first is you should write <= rather than =>. The second is you put the loop condition in the wrong place (it should be between the two semicolons). And lastly you're not assigning new values to num1 (so it never increases).

In addition, you don't need num2 (although it's not a mistake to use it, it makes it a bit less clear).

The final code should look like this:

```
int num1 = 1;
for (num1 = 1; num1 <= 99; num1 += 2)
    System.out.println(num1);
```

Plus, I'm pretty sure you're coding in Java and not JavaScript (they're two different things).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is no necessity of defining data type in Javascript.
That being said you do not need int num1 or num2.

This answer is valid if you are using Javascript not JAVA

Instead can be done this way

```
for (i = 1; i < 99 ; i++){
    if(i%2 !== 0){
    console.log(i);
    }else{}

}
```